# How to create a web app with ubuntu one sync

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu, synchronization

I have found on the website of ubuntu one API documentation ([store files in the cloud](http://www.example.com/)) for developers ... But since I'm only a beginner, I did not understand how I should use this documentation .. My intention is to create a web app (html, css, js, php) with Ubuntu One sync ... How should I apply the documentation??

Comment: Start by figuring out how to build web applications http://goo.gl/q5PJM, then learn how to use the APIs of others to do something useful http://goo.gl/cr5TN, then figure out how to use Ubuntu One's API to do something useful in your webapp http://goo.gl/ktWmD.